# listen to a conversation using port forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables, portforwarding, pjsip, netcat

I have been able to make a call using SIP client [Pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm) from one linux computer to another one. in case you have not heard of this user agent, explaining it's functionality is quite easy. It uses IP and port number of each linux to create a unique ID and then calling to this specific ID is possible.
Now i have not studied port forwarding so thoroughly but i suppose what it does is to forward whatever data that comes in it, to another "port" or "IP and port".
So i thought to myself if my calling application is using ports and IPs to send and receive voice i should be able to forward those specific ports to a second or third port (or IP and port) and listen to the conversation on a third computer.

so here is what i did:

supposing that **linux A machine** has the following Identification info: `IP:192.168.1.11`  `UDP port# : 1111`

and second Linux machine , **Linux B** has the following identification : `IP:192.168.1.22`  `UDP port# : 2222`

if i do the following using **IPtables** i should be able to hear that side of conversation which is being received on **linux B** on a **Linux C** (with the following identification info: `IP:192.168.1.33`  `UDP port# : 3333`)

**run this on Linux B :**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 2222 -j DNAT
--to-destination 192.168.1.33:3333    //forward port 2222 to Linux C on port 3333
```

**run this on linux C:**

```
aplay | nc -l -u 3333     //listen on the specified UDP port
```

but i dont get anything on linux C.
can anyone tell me why this is not working? other strategies to do such are also welcome.

Comment: Is routing activated on linux B ( /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward '1' ) , as iptable chain FORDWARD a Policy ACCEPT. More over SIP is a complex protocl and control connections are not the same as data stream, and there are many mecanism for NAT traversal ... Not as easy. What is overall goal, to tap and existing traffic ? forwarding will just forward it ( hence if you listen to soembody he won't get its voice data ... )...

Answer (score 0):

Initially, a see two small possible problems:

- In Linux B: you should also have an ACCEPT policy in FORDWARD chain.
- In Linux C: you should invert `aplay` and `nc` order on listening command line: `nc -l -u 3333 | aplay`

Hope this helps